# html dropdown submenu not functioning properly in mobile size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am actually new to HTML and CSS I am facing an issue with menu. this problem only occurs while I open in mobile but works perfectly on the desktop.

Here the problem is while I checking this in mobile only up to submenu level 1 is opening and while I click the submenu level 1 to open submenu level 2 it rolls back.

```css
#top-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: auto;
    color: #777777;
    padding: 10px 0 2px 0;
    border-top: 4px solid #33699e;
}
#top-menu.navbar { min-height: 35px !important }
#top-menu p.text-right span { margin-left: 15px }
a.logo.navbar-brand { color: #33699e }
.logo {
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    font-weight: 0;
    font-size: 27px;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 15px 15px 25px 0;
    margin-right: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #33699e;
}
#top-menu .navbar-header small {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
ul.top-links li { padding: 5px 0 }
.top-contact ol li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
#main-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #377cb7, #397db8);
    min-height: 30px;
}
#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#main-menu.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.navbar-collapse { padding-left: 0 }
#main-menu .nav > li > a { padding: 10px 10px }
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle { border-color: #fff; background-color: #fff; }
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus { background: #ededed; }
.navbar-toggle {
   /* float: none !important;*/
    color: #3772ac;
}
.navbar-toggle i { text-align: center }
#main-menu i.fa.fa-bars { font-size: 10px }
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand { color: #33699e }
.dropdown-menu > li > a,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-family: 'Sintony', sans-serif;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
#main-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #33699e !important;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    border-color: #33699e;
}
#main-menu .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s;
  text-align: center;
}
ol.social-icons li {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 5px !important;
}
ol.social-icons li a:hover,
ol.social-icons li a:focus { color: #ffffff !important }
ol.social-icons li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #33699e;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 4px 8px !important;
    margin: 0px -6px !important;
}
ol.social-icons li:hover a { background: #33699e }
#main-menu .navbar-form {
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#main-menu .form-control {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-color: #656565;
    background: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
#main-menu .input-group-btn button.btn.btn-default {
    background: transparent;
    border-color: #656565;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
    color: #222 !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus { background-color: transparent }
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #33699e;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myMenu">
                        <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/home_view/index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#">submenu level 1</a>
                                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu level 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu level 2 </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu level 2 </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                
                               
                                
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/blog_view/index">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="smoth-scroll"><a href="#contact">Reviews</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="smoth-scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/home_view/sitemap">Site Map</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2"></div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helpful, you can edit style as your needs.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);


if ($(window).width() > 768){
$(function(){
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
});
}
```

```css
.marginBottom-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #cccccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #555;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top marginBottom-0" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```